# How to use a simcard on PC

Tags: drivers

What drivers should I install to make the simcard slot in HP EliteBook 2570p PC usable without using a modem. Running on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Probably need `modem-manager`:  https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-cellular-connections